# k8s - ingress-nginx - rewrite-target annotation causing 504

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, nginx-ingress

I've deployed a default nginx ingress controller `v1.5.1` via helm (`kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx v4.4.0`) to my AKS cluster. Running kubernetes `v1.24.6`.

I have created the following ingress to reach my app service/pod. The idea is to remove the prefix path (`/api/v1`) entirely in the rewrite.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/v1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port: 
              number: 8080
```

This results in a 504 (150s timeout). The app pod is healthy, and when I remove the rewrite-target annotation the controller becomes responsive again.

What is unusual is that I see no request log entries in the controller pod whatsoever when attempting to use the rewrite-target annotation. I've added `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: "true"` but it makes no difference.

Following documentation here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

What am I missing?

Comment: As you said if you remove the rewrite-target annotation path regex, all works as expected. Then try to add the below given annotation in yaml and check  it. This might work without removing regex also.  Let me know if this resolves your issue.

   
      `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"`

Comment: @HemanthKumar Adding the regex annotation did not change the behavior unfortunately.

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? If so can you post it here.

Comment: When the rewrite-target annotation is set, the controller pod does not produce any request logs. There are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of Kubernetes on the cluster. I created a new cluster running `v1.23.12` using the same ingress and had no issues with the path rewrite working as expected. To confirm, I tried `v1.24.3` and `v1.24.6` again on new clusters and in both instances reproduced the timeout.